# Is using Unity Tweak on Ubuntu 14.04 safe?

Tags: unity, configuration, customization, unity-tweak-tool

I just installed Unity Tweak from the Ubuntu Software Center. The program have a lot of different customization options, like transparent bars and more options for windows snapping.

But, can those or others changes cause any system problems (like compatibility issues)? (Asking this because Ubuntu by default doesn't give those options, maybe to prevent issues?).

Thank you guys for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity-tweak is just another tweaking tool such as Ubuntu-tweak or gnome-tweak, yet it's just another application, thus it doesn't to have included in Ubuntu itself since many others aren't also, in addition no tweaking tool was available before by default, then this is not an exception.

Would this affect your system, or cause some problems!! Normally no but, this app as other apps may have some bugs that affect your system. This is not a rule, it's just a possibility that is related to every application you are installing in your system.

Anyway, you can give it a try.